# How to work with Baccini et al.'s biomass map from ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, layers

[Baccini et al. (2012)](http://www.nature.com/nclimate/journal/v2/n3/full/nclimate1354.html) has produced one of the best biomass maps available for the world. One can find the map from one of ArcGIS repositories [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2332b43bc5454127bfde21e894c89a51).

I downloaded the `.pkinfo` file for that map but I could not work with it. The map is 'unselectable' in ArcMap. The only thing I managed to do was to export it as a `.lyr` file, but that is not helpful at all.

I am not really a GIS expert so I cannot tell if I missing something really basic about that map but I wonder if there is an easy way to be able to work with that map in ArcMap or even in R? For instance, to be able to crop it and calculate mean values, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is not really an answer to the my question, but if you are interested in the biomass map I found a link from where you can download the actual data: http://whrc.org/publications-data/datasets/pantropical-national-level-carbon-stock/